# why my handler does not give me the exit status in C?

Tags: c, signals, fork

currently I have the code like that:

```
void handler(int sig) {
  int stat;
  wait(&stat);
  if (WIFEXITED(stat))
    printf("%d", WEXITSTATUS(stat));
}
int main() {
  int i;
  pid_t pids[5];
  signal(SIGCHLD, handler);
  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    if ((pids[i] = fork()) == 0) {
      printf("1");
      while (1) ; /* inf loop */
    }
  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    kill(pids[i], SIGKILL);
  sleep(1);
  return 2;
}
```

All necessary head files were included such as `<signal.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`

I assume that I would at least get the exit status when running, but there is no output. Why is that?

Comment: there are a lot of functions that should not be invoked within a signal handler,  `printf()` is such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the child processes don't exit, they are *killed*. They are terminated by a signal. Use `WIFSIGNALED` to check if the process was killed by a signal, and `WTERMSIG` to get the signal number.

For a process to "exit" it has to either return from the `main` function, or call `exit`.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will do more research about signals

Comment: @Foo.Li If the answer was useful then please upvote it. :) And if it solved your problem then you should accept it.